# Laravel Mix Critical CSS - criticalCss is not a function

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I have been trying to compile Webpack with laravel-mix, laravel-mix-purgecss, and laravel-mix-criticalcss. But I have been facing issues compiling it with laravel-mix-criticalcss. If I comment the criticalcss in webpack.mix.js, it works fine, but with criticalcss it throws an error. I have upgraded npm and all packages, but whenever I try to compile webpack, it throws this error:

> [webpack-cli] TypeError:
> mix.js(...).options(...).postCss(...).options(...).sass(...).sass(...).criticalCss
> is not a function

I have included laravel-mix-criticalcss in webpack.mix.js

```
require('laravel-mix-criticalcss');
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "intersection-observer": "^0.12.0",
        "laravel-vue-pagination": "^3.0.0",
        "sass-migrator": "^1.5.4",
        "v-lazy-image": "^2.1.1",
        "vanilla-lazyload": "^17.6.1",
        "vue-clickaway": "^2.2.2",
        "vue-slider-component": "^3.2.15",
        "vue-sweetalert2": "^5.0.2",
        "vuedraggable": "^2.24.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.4",
        "axios": "^0.26.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
        "bs-custom-file-input": "^1.3.4",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "jquery": "^3.6.0",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.43",
        "laravel-mix-criticalcss": "^0.1.0",
        "laravel-mix-purgecss": "^6.0.0",
        "laravel-mix-workbox": "^0.1.4",
        "livewire-sortable": "^0.2.2",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
        "postcss": "^8.4.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^5.0.0",
        "sass": "^1.49.9",
        "sass-loader": "^12.6.0",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.0.23",
        "vue": "^3.2.31",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
        "workbox-webpack-plugin": "^6.5.1"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a new version of Laravel Mix Critical.

```
npm i laravel-mix-criticalcss@latest --save-dev
```

Or use this package.json and do `npm install`.

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "intersection-observer": "^0.12.0",
        "laravel-vue-pagination": "^3.0.0",
        "sass-migrator": "^1.5.4",
        "v-lazy-image": "^2.1.1",
        "vanilla-lazyload": "^17.6.1",
        "vue-slider-component": "^3.2.15",
        "vue-sweetalert2": "^5.0.2",
        "vuedraggable": "^2.24.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.4",
        "axios": "^0.26.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
        "bs-custom-file-input": "^1.3.4",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "jquery": "^3.6.0",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.43",
        "laravel-mix-criticalcss": "^1.0.2",
        "laravel-mix-purgecss": "^6.0.0",
        "laravel-mix-workbox": "^0.1.4",
        "livewire-sortable": "^0.2.2",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
        "postcss": "^8.4.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^5.0.0",
        "sass": "^1.49.9",
        "sass-loader": "^12.6.0",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.0.23",
        "vue": "^3.2.31",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
        "workbox-webpack-plugin": "^6.5.1"
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that but then it runs into dependencies issues:

`Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer laravel-mix@"^2.1.7" from laravel-mix-criticalcss@0.1.0
npm WARN node_modules/laravel-mix-criticalcss
npm WARN   dev laravel-mix-criticalcss@"0.1.0" from the root project
`
So `npm audit fix --force` changes it to `0.1.0`

Comment: The only dependency issue I can see is with vue-clickaway and that codebase hasn't been updated in 4 years.